# Could someone provide an example of what the `weaken` function would do?

Tags: haskell, types

In `Thinking With Types`, Exercise 11.2-i is to write the function with the following type signature.

`weaken :: OpenSum f ts -> OpenSum f (x ': ts)`

```
data OpenSum (f :: k -> Type) (ts :: [k]) where
  UnsafeOpenSum :: Int -> f t -> OpenSum f ts
```

The paragraph prior to the exercise is supposed to, I think, provide enough context to know what this function accomplishes, but it's not clear to me.

> In practice, it is also useful to be able to widen the possibilities of an open sum. A new function, weaken, tacks a x type in front of the list of possibilities.

If I had some examples of this function being used, it would go a long way towards me completing this exercise.

Comment: I think the unsafe implementation obscures what `OpenSum` is supposed to do. Does the book not also show the slower safe implementation? I.e. `data OpenSum f ts where { Here :: f t -> OpenSum f (t : ts) ; There :: OpenSum f ts -> OpenSum f (x : ts) }`. Now `weaken` is obvious. The only remaining question is how the unsafe and safe versions are related.

Comment: @Noughtmare I think the idea is to use types to make the use of UnsafeOpenSum safe, which was demonstrated in the prior example `decompose`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `UnsafeOpenSum :: Int -> f t -> OpenSum f ts` the list `ts` is completely unrelated to the other type variables, so this constructor can produce values of type `OpenSum f ts` for any `ts`.

Hence, we get

```
weaken :: OpenSum f ts -> OpenSum f (x ': ts)
weaken (UnsafeOpenSum i ft) = UnsafeOpenSum newI ft
   where newI = ...  -- To do
```

Note that the two terms `UnsafeOpenSum i ft` look equal (except for the `i` part), but are of distinct types.

```
weaken (UnsafeOpenSum i ft) = UnsafeOpenSum newI ft
       \- :: OpenSum f ts     |
                              \- :: OpenSum f (x :' ts)
```

Also, we need a new index `newI`, which we can compute in terms of `i`.

Since having access to the constructor allows one to choose any list `ts` in the type, the constructor is named `Unsafe....` to remind users that one should use it only to implement safe primitives (like `weaken`). After that, users are expected to use the safe primitives without accessing the lower level constructor.

Comment: This type checks but is not correct. You need to change `i` as well.

Comment: @Noughtmare Thank you, I just realized what that integer was meant to represent. I'll leave that part for the OP to solve, so not to spoil too much.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to do this myself but felt I needed more information as to what I was supposed to accomplish. This is very helpful.